# import org.apache.wicket.extensions.yui.calendar cannot be resolved - maven

Tags: java, maven, datepicker, calendar, wicket

I'm attempting to use the DatePicker function.  I have the jar loaded at

```
C:\Users\Jonas\.m2\repository\org\apache\wicket\wicket-datetime\1.4.14\wicket-datetime-1.4.14\org\apache\wicket\extensions\yui\calendar
```

and the datepicker class is present along with the standard contents of the calendar jar.

The dependency has been imported in maven and the following is embedded amongst a number of working dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-datetime</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.14</version>
    </dependency>
```

However the lines

```
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.yui.calendar.*;
```

with * or any class in ~.yui.calendar throws the exception

```
the import org.apache.wicket.extensions.yui.calendar cannot be resolved
```

There is a number of other wicket files being imported using the same system, however this is the only one that throws an error.  I've seen no special requirements for this class while I was troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\Jonas\.m2\repository\org\apache\wicket\wicket-datetime\1.4.14\wicket-datetime-1.4.14\org\apache\wicket\extensions\yui\calendar
```

This looks wrong.
Here it is:

```
~/.m2/repository/org/apache/wicket/wicket-datetime/6.20.0/wicket-datetime-6.20.0.jar
```

i.e. it is a **.jar**

Comment: Yeah I unzipped in 7zip it to view the contents.